# Uniqueness of the direct product decomposition of inclusions of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups, computational-group-theory

This post is a generalization of [Uniqueness of the direct product decomposition of finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/908033/84284).
Here we look **inclusions** of finite groups $(H \subset G)$ instead of just finite groups.

*Definition*: Two inclusions of finite groups are equivalent, $(A \subset B) \sim (C \subset D)$, if: $(A/A_B \subset B/A_B) \simeq (C/C_D \subset D/C_D)$ with $A_B$ the [normal core](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/908033/84284) of $A$ in $B$.

*Remark*: The equivalence class of $(A \subset B)$ is the same that the conjugacy class of a transitive permutation group $G$ (see [this GAP Data Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/trans.html)) with $(A \subset B) \sim (G_1 \subset G)$.

*Definition*: An inclusion of groups $(H \subset G)$ is **indecomposable** if (for $H_i \le G_i)$: "$(H \subset G) \sim (H_1 \times H_2 \subset G_1 \times G_2)$" $\Rightarrow$  "$\exists i$ such that $H_i = G_i$"

*Examples*: The maximal inclusions are indecomposable.
*Warning*: $(H \subset G)$ maximal (*a fortiori* indecomposable)  $\not \Rightarrow$ $G$ indecomposable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/913510/84284)).

An inclusion of finite groups  decomposes into a direct product of indecomposable inclusions: $$(H \subset G) \sim (\prod_i H_i \subset \prod_i G_i)$$  with $(H_i \subset G_i)$ an indecomposable inclusion of finite groups $\forall i$.

**Question**: Is this decomposition unique (up to permutation and equivalence $\sim$)?

*Remark*: The finite group case comes from the the [Krull–Schmidt theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem). It generalizes into the [Kurosh-Ore theorem](http://planetmath.org/kuroshoretheorem) in the general theory of [modular lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice), with a specific relevant additional result if the lattice is [distributive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice). Perhaps we can use this theorem for answering the question.